# Bootstrap action dropdown is not working inside table-responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap dropdown is not working in responsive as well as in desktop because i'm using this inside `table-responsive` and there is `overflow` property.

anybody can solve it?
Thanks

```css
.dropdown-toggle{ cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Password</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Created By</th>
<th>Registration Date</th>
<th>Action</th>


</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>john@example.com</td>
<td>Password</td>
<td>Phone</td>
<td>Created By</td>
<td>Registration Date</td>
<td>
<div class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i>
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu menuScroll">
<li><a href="">Details</a></li>
<li><a href="">Document</a></li>
<li><a href="">Care Plan</a></li>
<li><a href="">Health Ins Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Workers Comp Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Personal Injury Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Work Related Injuries</a></li>
<li><a href="">Motor Vehicle Accident</a></li>
<li><a href="">Medical History</a></li>
<li><a href="">Past Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Upcoming Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Authorization</a></li>

<li><a href="">Child Patient</a></li>
<li><a href="">Billing Record</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/admin/DeletePatient?ID=6476" class="fa fa-trash-o btnDelete" data-toggle="confirmation" style="color:red;" title="" data-original-title="click yes to delete"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>john@example.com</td>
<td>Password</td>
<td>Phone</td>
<td>Created By</td>
<td>Registration Date</td>
<td>
<div class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i>
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu menuScroll">
<li><a href="">Details</a></li>
<li><a href="">Document</a></li>
<li><a href="">Care Plan</a></li>
<li><a href="">Health Ins Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Workers Comp Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Personal Injury Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Work Related Injuries</a></li>
<li><a href="">Motor Vehicle Accident</a></li>
<li><a href="">Medical History</a></li>
<li><a href="">Past Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Upcoming Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Authorization</a></li>

<li><a href="">Child Patient</a></li>
<li><a href="">Billing Record</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/admin/DeletePatient?ID=6476" class="fa fa-trash-o btnDelete" data-toggle="confirmation" style="color:red;" title="" data-original-title="click yes to delete"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>john@example.com</td>
<td>Password</td>
<td>Phone</td>
<td>Created By</td>
<td>Registration Date</td>
<td>
<div class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i>
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu menuScroll">
<li><a href="">Details</a></li>
<li><a href="">Document</a></li>
<li><a href="">Care Plan</a></li>
<li><a href="">Health Ins Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Workers Comp Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Personal Injury Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Work Related Injuries</a></li>
<li><a href="">Motor Vehicle Accident</a></li>
<li><a href="">Medical History</a></li>
<li><a href="">Past Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Upcoming Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Authorization</a></li>

<li><a href="">Child Patient</a></li>
<li><a href="">Billing Record</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/admin/DeletePatient?ID=6476" class="fa fa-trash-o btnDelete" data-toggle="confirmation" style="color:red;" title="" data-original-title="click yes to delete"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>john@example.com</td>
<td>Password</td>
<td>Phone</td>
<td>Created By</td>
<td>Registration Date</td>
<td>
<div class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i>
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu menuScroll">
<li><a href="">Details</a></li>
<li><a href="">Document</a></li>
<li><a href="">Care Plan</a></li>
<li><a href="">Health Ins Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Workers Comp Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Personal Injury Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Work Related Injuries</a></li>
<li><a href="">Motor Vehicle Accident</a></li>
<li><a href="">Medical History</a></li>
<li><a href="">Past Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Upcoming Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Authorization</a></li>

<li><a href="">Child Patient</a></li>
<li><a href="">Billing Record</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/admin/DeletePatient?ID=6476" class="fa fa-trash-o btnDelete" data-toggle="confirmation" style="color:red;" title="" data-original-title="click yes to delete"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>john@example.com</td>
<td>Password</td>
<td>Phone</td>
<td>Created By</td>
<td>Registration Date</td>
<td>
<div class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i>
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu menuScroll">
<li><a href="">Details</a></li>
<li><a href="">Document</a></li>
<li><a href="">Care Plan</a></li>
<li><a href="">Health Ins Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Workers Comp Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Personal Injury Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Work Related Injuries</a></li>
<li><a href="">Motor Vehicle Accident</a></li>
<li><a href="">Medical History</a></li>
<li><a href="">Past Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Upcoming Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Authorization</a></li>

<li><a href="">Child Patient</a></li>
<li><a href="">Billing Record</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/admin/DeletePatient?ID=6476" class="fa fa-trash-o btnDelete" data-toggle="confirmation" style="color:red;" title="" data-original-title="click yes to delete"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

</div>
</td>
</tr>



</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually it is working in all view, but visibility problem there

Comment: Yes i want to my dropdown should be appear over table not inside while both condition responsive as well as desktop too.

Comment: @RohitVerma will this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vibs2006/6Lje6cLL/) work for you?

Comment: @vibs2006 its working fine but i want dropdown should be appear over table not inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/n2omqzpu/1/

```js
$('a[class="dropdown-toggle"]').click(function(){
 var pos = $(this).closest('td').position();
  var ele = $(this).siblings('ul.dropdown-menu');
  var width = $(document).width() - 200;

  if( width > pos.left) {
    $(ele).css({
      left: pos.left,
      top: (pos.top + 20)
  });
  } else {
     $(ele).css({
      left: (pos.left - 180),
      top: (pos.top + 20)
     });
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown-toggle{ cursor:pointer;}

.dropdown-menu{
  position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Password</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Created By</th>
<th>Registration Date</th>
<th>Action</th>


</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>john@example.com</td>
<td>Password</td>
<td>Phone</td>
<td>Created By</td>
<td>Registration Date</td>
<td>
<div class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i>
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu menuScroll">
<li><a href="">Details</a></li>
<li><a href="">Document</a></li>
<li><a href="">Care Plan</a></li>
<li><a href="">Health Ins Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Workers Comp Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Personal Injury Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Work Related Injuries</a></li>
<li><a href="">Motor Vehicle Accident</a></li>
<li><a href="">Medical History</a></li>
<li><a href="">Past Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Upcoming Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Authorization</a></li>

<li><a href="">Child Patient</a></li>
<li><a href="">Billing Record</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/admin/DeletePatient?ID=6476" class="fa fa-trash-o btnDelete" data-toggle="confirmation" style="color:red;" title="" data-original-title="click yes to delete"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>john@example.com</td>
<td>Password</td>
<td>Phone</td>
<td>Created By</td>
<td>Registration Date</td>
<td>
<div class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i>
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu menuScroll">
<li><a href="">Details</a></li>
<li><a href="">Document</a></li>
<li><a href="">Care Plan</a></li>
<li><a href="">Health Ins Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Workers Comp Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Personal Injury Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Work Related Injuries</a></li>
<li><a href="">Motor Vehicle Accident</a></li>
<li><a href="">Medical History</a></li>
<li><a href="">Past Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Upcoming Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Authorization</a></li>

<li><a href="">Child Patient</a></li>
<li><a href="">Billing Record</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/admin/DeletePatient?ID=6476" class="fa fa-trash-o btnDelete" data-toggle="confirmation" style="color:red;" title="" data-original-title="click yes to delete"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>john@example.com</td>
<td>Password</td>
<td>Phone</td>
<td>Created By</td>
<td>Registration Date</td>
<td>
<div class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i>
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu menuScroll">
<li><a href="">Details</a></li>
<li><a href="">Document</a></li>
<li><a href="">Care Plan</a></li>
<li><a href="">Health Ins Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Workers Comp Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Personal Injury Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Work Related Injuries</a></li>
<li><a href="">Motor Vehicle Accident</a></li>
<li><a href="">Medical History</a></li>
<li><a href="">Past Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Upcoming Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Authorization</a></li>

<li><a href="">Child Patient</a></li>
<li><a href="">Billing Record</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/admin/DeletePatient?ID=6476" class="fa fa-trash-o btnDelete" data-toggle="confirmation" style="color:red;" title="" data-original-title="click yes to delete"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>john@example.com</td>
<td>Password</td>
<td>Phone</td>
<td>Created By</td>
<td>Registration Date</td>
<td>
<div class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i>
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu menuScroll">
<li><a href="">Details</a></li>
<li><a href="">Document</a></li>
<li><a href="">Care Plan</a></li>
<li><a href="">Health Ins Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Workers Comp Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Personal Injury Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Work Related Injuries</a></li>
<li><a href="">Motor Vehicle Accident</a></li>
<li><a href="">Medical History</a></li>
<li><a href="">Past Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Upcoming Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Authorization</a></li>

<li><a href="">Child Patient</a></li>
<li><a href="">Billing Record</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/admin/DeletePatient?ID=6476" class="fa fa-trash-o btnDelete" data-toggle="confirmation" style="color:red;" title="" data-original-title="click yes to delete"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>john@example.com</td>
<td>Password</td>
<td>Phone</td>
<td>Created By</td>
<td>Registration Date</td>
<td>
<div class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i>
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu menuScroll">
<li><a href="">Details</a></li>
<li><a href="">Document</a></li>
<li><a href="">Care Plan</a></li>
<li><a href="">Health Ins Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Workers Comp Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Personal Injury Info</a></li>
<li><a href="">Work Related Injuries</a></li>
<li><a href="">Motor Vehicle Accident</a></li>
<li><a href="">Medical History</a></li>
<li><a href="">Past Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Upcoming Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Authorization</a></li>

<li><a href="">Child Patient</a></li>
<li><a href="">Billing Record</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/admin/DeletePatient?ID=6476" class="fa fa-trash-o btnDelete" data-toggle="confirmation" style="color:red;" title="" data-original-title="click yes to delete"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

</div>
</td>
</tr>



</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Little bit of dynamic calculation is required for positioning the `dropdown` element. Make the `dropdown` as **position fixe**d.

Answer (score 0):

In My system it is working. Just change your css code like this.

```
.dropdown-menu {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: -135px;
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
float: left;
min-width: 160px;
padding: 5px 0;
margin: 2px 0 0;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: left;
list-style: none;
background-color: #fff;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
```

}

If you need, chenge left value increased or decreased (left: -135px)

Comment: @Melbin As you can see in question description ***Bootstrap dropdown is not working in responsive.*** And you added ***In My system it is working*** in your answer. Why you are not looking that question is about responsive... :)

Comment: @RohitSharma In responsive dropdown is working. But, the whole contents is not showing in the Dropdown. Means scroll bar is not working like Desktop.